# Swift segue - Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to open "Select city" controller, when selectedCityId is 0 (Undefined) - to select a city. In my root view controller (MainVC) in viewDidLoad():

```
let selectedCityId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("selectedCityId")

    if(selectedCityId == 0){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("startupSegue", sender: self)
    } else {
        ....
    }
```

So the startupSegue opens settingsViewController (SettingsVC) modally! Both - MainVC and SettingsVC have embed in Navigation View Controller.

There are 2 warnings:

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is
>   discouraged "myapp.MainVC: 0x7fee8871e670".
>
> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   "UINavigationController: 0x7fee8872c950".

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Try setting the segue in storyboard to not animate. since I assume since your doing this in viewDidLoad that you want the selectedCityVC to be presented instantly when the app starts up?

Comment: Yes, but does it solves a problem?

Comment: Your VC isn't ready to perform segues yet. It's view has loaded (viewDidLoad) but hasn't landed in the view hierarchy yet.

Answer (score 5):

I had a same warning and fixed it by moving code to -viewDidAppear. One thing you should be aware is that -viewDidLoad is called only once while -viewDidAppear maybe called multiple times if page becomes visible so you need to add additional mechanism to skip performing segue again.

Answer (score 2):

Moving code to -viewDidAppear is a good idea but I would also suggest to perform your seque call from the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("startupSegue", sender: self)
})
```

**Swift 3**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
  {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "startupSegue", sender: self)
}
```